# Can't update value in my tables

Tags: php, mysql

Can i ask for your help with my problem in my code. i have this update_client.php as my function to update the details in my edit.php page.

but as i click on save it doesn't change the value. I wonder where did i go wrong. can somebody please help me with it. I would really appreciate it. Thank

here is the code for my update_client.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("location:../efeedback/login2.php"); 

}
require_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$client_user = $_POST['client_user'];
$client_pass = $_POST['client_pass'];
$initials = $_POST['initials'];

$sql="UPDATE client_users SET name = '$name', company = '$company', email = '$email', client_user = '$client_user', client_pass = '$client_pass', initials = '$initials' WHERE id = '$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){

header("location:add_client.php");
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Comment: where are you giving value of id??

Comment: Darvex seems correct , also you are horribly vulnerable to sql injection attacks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql="UPDATE client_users SET name = '$name', company = '$company', email = '$email', client_user = '$client_user', client_pass = '$client_pass', initials = '$initials' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

By the looks of it, you forgot to set value for $id variable

Answer (score 0):

Seems you haven't set value for `id`

```
$sql="UPDATE client_users SET name = '$name', company = '$company', email = '$email', client_user = '$client_user', client_pass = '$client_pass', initials = '$initials' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set value for `$id`

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
...
$id = //you need set value for id, ex: $_GET['id'] or $_POST['id'];
```

If field `id` in your table is type number, you need do this:

```
$sql="UPDATE client_users SET name = '$name', company = '$company', email = '$email', client_user = '$client_user', client_pass = '$client_pass', initials = '$initials' WHERE id = $id";
```

Just `$id` not `'$id'`.

Comment: i set value for id, $id = $_POST['id']; but still i didn't change the value after save..

Comment: Are you sure variable `$id` set correct value? you can check $_POST value by `<?php print_r($_POST)?>`

Comment: Thanks its now working, i changed the '$id' to just $id. hmmm it did change but not automatically when i get back to may client list page, i still have to refresh the page a couple of times.. do you know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Hmm... i not too sure, but if successfully updated and your code `header("location:add_client.php");` work fine i think all be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Always you have to read your error message. in this script you given Undefined variable id.